# Can an INA219 current sensor operate with a FET body diode present over the sensing pins?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, current-measurement

I'm designing a board with optional current sensing modules (based on [INA219](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina219.pdf)) that can be plugged into it for monitoring the current on some 12V lines that go to peripheral devices.

The schematic for the main board looks like this:

[image: Schematic]

The `12V_INT` line is the 12V supply on this board, and the `12V_OUT_1` line goes to a connector that is used by the peripheral whose current load is being monitored.

The idea here is that when the sense module is not present, the `CSENSE_PRSNT_1` line is pulled to ground by the 10K resistor, so Q3 is on and Q4 is off. This allows current to flow from `12V_IN` directly to `12V_OUT_1`, powering the peripheral. The LED is off, indicating that no module is plugged in.

The module board plugs into CONN7 and bridges `12V_INT` to `CSENSE_PRSNT_1`. This raises `CSENSE_PRSNT_1` to 12V, switching Q3 off and Q4 on. This turns the LED on, and blocks direct current flow between `12V_INT` and `12V_OUT_1`. The module board then has a 10mΩ precision resistor across the `12V_INT` and `12V_OUT_1` lines, and the INA219's sense pins are connected over it.

As far as I understand, this should work. The body diode of Q3 is pointing in the wrong direction to allow current flow, so it shouldn't affect the reading. The body diode breakdown voltage should not be exceeded, and if it is I have bigger problems. I don't see anything in the INA219 datasheet that indicates there would be a problem. Am I correct here? Did I miss something?

Comment: The specs are clear Differential (V IN+ – V IN– ) (2) –26 26 V
Analog Inputs
IN+, IN–
Common-mode(V IN+ + V IN– ) / 2 -0.3 26 V

Comment: are you asking is this safe for the part? or will it distort the readings?

Comment: @Jasen I'm asking about both, but I don't require precision beyond about 1-2% as this is mostly for keeping an eye on things and there are no safety-critical features dependent on the accuracy of the current monitor.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm not sure I follow what you're saying, beyond the fact that the device allows for up to 26V across the sense pins. I'm less concerned about exceeding those limits and more concerned about whether the body diode, or some other feature of the transistor, might mess with the sensing results. My gut says no, because the INA219 should just be measuring the voltage over the sense resistor and the transistor shouldn't affect that when the gate voltage is high, but I'm asking for clarification in case I missed something.

Comment: I dont see any issues there, except protection from ESD

Comment: Good shout on ESD protection. I've already got TVS diodes on the IO lines that run to peripherals, but forgot to add them for the I2C bus and the `CSENSE_PRSNT` line.

Comment: The only issue is that if the sense voltage is large enough and in the correct direction, the diode will become forward biased and allow some current to flow without going through the shunt. As long as you make sure that can't happen then it should not cause any errors in the measurement.

Comment: @mkeith The breakdown voltage is around 60V, so at that point the INA219 providing an accurate current reading would be the least of my worries (either `12V_INT` would need to be above 60V or `12V_OUT_1` would need to be below -48V, both of which would lead to catastrophic failure anyway).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I was thinking of reverse flow. Under reverse current flow conditions, the body diode could become forward biased (if the FET is off).

Comment: @mkeith Ah, yes, true. I guess that could happen if the `12V_OUT_1` voltage rises above `12V_INT` for whatever reason. I can almost certainly get away with a low Vf schottky diode in series with the PFET to prevent that.

Comment: Only if you think it could actually happen. For example if you are driving a motor which could go into regen. Even if it does happen it will not do any real harm unless the shunt voltage climbs fairly high. I just mentioned it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @mkeith The `12V_OUT_1` line is actually being driven into some Cat5e cables for driving switch panels around a building, so the most likely failure case would be that someone (read: me, when not paying attention) connects one of those cables to a -48V PoE injector or something. Probably won't happen, but I found some cheap Schottky diodes with 80V reverse bias blocking voltage and only a 0.3V forward drop at 200mA, and the output pins have 250mA polyfuses on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good to me too:

The turned off mosfet will basically disappear from the sense circuit and all current will flow through the resistor instead, so everything should work just fine.

I initially thought (before I read your whole question) that you intended to use the internal resistance of the mosfet as the current sense resistor and were concerned about possible damage to the INA219.  but that would also work.